# Realtime Collect GC metrics for .Net Core 2.1 App running on Linux

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, metrics, asp.net-core-2.1, lttng

I want to realtime collect GC metrics from applications running on Linux  in production. I have an assumption that it is not possible to obtain reliable data about the application memory state(all memory types) running from docker or kubernetes. Accordingly, the data received from the GC may also be not unreliable or completely unreliable.

Perhaps someone faced with similar issues and can share experiences
Very grateful for any answer.

Comment: have you read https://lttng.org/blog/2018/08/28/bringing-dotnet-perf-analysis-to-linux/

Comment: @CharmisVarghese yes, I have read this